# Replace normal function with an anonymous function

Tags: javascript, oop, anonymous-function

How do I use an anonymous function to replace a normal function that accepts `this` and returns results?  Please describe how variables are being sent to and from the anonymous function.

For instance, replace:

```
function myFunc(myProp){return [1*myProp,2*myProp,3*myProp];} 
this.myProp=2;
var myArray1=myFunc(this.myProp);
```

with something like:

```
var myArray2=function(){return [1*this.myProp,2*this.myProp,3*this.myProp];}
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: the second one is still a function definition, you just assign it to a variable.

Comment: @Hogan.  I am only using myFunc() once, so to streamline the code, I wanted to encapsulate it.

Comment: @Ibu.  Self imposed homework.  Just trying to figure out how it works.

Comment: @user1032531 - I don't believe making the code less clear is streamlining it.  Just because a function is only called once does not mean it should be refactored.  This is esp true in JavaScript which changes the lexical meaning depending on where it is declared.

Comment: Learning is one thing, but for your purpose you can as well assign the function body expression to myArray2 than using function.

Comment: @gp.  The array a fictional example.  Real use will be a search function.

Comment: regarding your question, I invite you to read this [function declaration and function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This maybe what you want:

```
var myArray2=(function(myProp){
                return [1*myProp,2*myProp,3*myProp];}
             )(this.myProp);
```

So here we define an anonymous function(because it doesn't have a name) and call it immediately. `this.myProp` will be passed as an argument.

Comment: Thanks Grame_mao.  This is exactly what I was trying to do. How come adding `(this.myProp)` made it return an array and not a function?  Also, as I understand it, without explicitly passing `this.myProp` and assigning it to `myProp`, I could still have accessed `this.myProp`, correct?  Still like your way much more.

Comment: @user1032531 well, if we have a function called F, then we use F() to invoke it. Here we define a function, then invoke it like the way we do to a normal function. 'This' will refer to the object on which your function is called, since here is an anonymous function and we call it directly, 'this' refers to Window object.

Comment: @user1032531 and you could have a look at gp's answer, it works too.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myArray2=(function(){return [1*this.myProp,2*this.myProp,3*this.myProp];}).call(this);
```

Any javascript function can be invoked using "call" method or "apply" method on the function.
In both ways, first argument is the context object that "this" variable refers to inside the function block.

More:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/h2ak8h2y(v=vs.94).aspx
http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2007/07/05/function-apply-and-function-call-in-javascript.aspx

Comment: maybe you care to explain?

Comment: call/apply method can be invoked on any function where first parameter is the context which "this" refers to in the function body.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is a little vague, so I can only guess that you want to add functions to predefined object. Thats can be done with `Prototype` property.

`FooBar = function(){
       this.foo = 1;
    }`

```
FooBar.prototype.getFoo = function() {
    return this.foo;
}
```